# How to configure sound output when multiple cards are installed?

Tags: audio, hdmi, sound-card, nvidia-settings

My laptop has both a Realtech HD audio sound chip and Nvidia high definition audio.

I noticed in sound settings in control panel that laptop speakers are driven by the realtech chip, instead if I use an external monitor (hdmi) the audio to the screen is managed by Nvidia hd audio.
The nvidia control panel does not help since it has just a link to the main Windows control panel soound settings window.

I tried to switch the laptop speakers to use Nvidia as well but I do not find any command for that (I like more the audio from Nvidia).

Actually I suspect that there is some wiring between Realtech and internal speakers and for external ones the audio is going through Nvidia since also the video must be redirected, but that's just my guess.

Is it possible to change this setting? If it is possible, How can I have all audio managed by Nvidia chip?

Comment: What OS are you using? In Windows you have to switch to the right audio device, but it depends on which OS you are using to give you the instructions. If you are running Windows 10, please also specify which sub version you are using, for example Windows 10 v1809.

Comment: Also, the NVidia audio is part of the HDMI connector, so yes, it is exclusive to when you are using an external hdmi monitor that has speakers.

Comment: @LPChip I use Windows 10 home, with the latest updates released a few days ago. In the audio settings of control panel I see the 2 audio devices, I can see some properties but I do not see any way to set the audio device. I suppose you are right in the second comment therefore there is no way to have Nvidia sound on laptop speakers or Realtek on hdmi.

Comment: Indeed. You can only use the Nvidia one when connected to HDMI. But in case you have a monitor connected and you want to switch audio between the speakers (realtek) and the monitor (nvidia) you can do this by clicking the speaker icon, and then change the dropdown at the very top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you run the latest version of Windows 10. Switching audio devices can be done by clicking the speaker icon, and then click the name of the audio device at the top. It will become a drop-down list if there are more than one audio devices.

Do note, that the realtek audio device is for your internal audio and will output to your speakers and/or headphones. The nvidia audio device is solely for sending audio over the HDMI port, which means you have to have a display with speakers attached to the HDMI port, such as a tv before you can see the nvidia audio device pop up in your config.

You cannot use the nvidia drivers but have the audio through your laptop speakers.